# Struct with access to inherited struct

Tags: c, inheritance, linked-list, structure, nodes

I'm trying to write some functions to work on a balanced binary tree.

First I wrote a typical binary tree interface. This encapsulates the general functionality associated with binary trees.

The tree has nodes

```
typedef struct Node
{
  Node* left;
  Node* right;
  Node* parent;

  int key;

  void* value;

} Node;
```

and some functions that do `insert`, `remove` and `search`.

Now I want to extend that interface to work on a different types of binary trees, which inherits `Node`.

```
typedef enum Color
{
  RED,
  BLACK

} Color;

typedef struct RBTreeNode
{
  Node* genericNode;
  Color color;

} RBTreeNode;
```

`RBTree` refers to [Red-Black Trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree)

The trouble ensues when I try to write a "tree repair" function.

```
void repairRBTree(Node* nodeInserted)
{

  // If nodeInserted's parent is NULL, nodeInserted is the root of the tree.
  // Red-Black tree properties suggest root node's color be black.
  if (nodeInserted->parent == NULL)
    {
      RBTreeNode* nodeInsertedTC = (RBTreeNode*)nodeInserted;
      nodeInsertedTC->color      = BLACK;
    }

  // If nodeInserted's parent's color is BLACK, nodeInserted has replaced a RED NULL node.
  // Red-Black tree properties suggest RED node's parent be BLACK,
  // which is the case currently, so there's nothing to be done.
  else if (nodeInserted->parent->(COLOR??))
    {
      return;
    }
}
```

In this `if` statement,

```
  if (nodeInserted->parent == NULL)
    {
      RBTreeNode* nodeInsertedTC = (RBTreeNode*)nodeInserted;
      nodeInsertedTC->color      = BLACK;
    }
```

if I had previously cast `nodeInserted` as `Node*`, that means the pointer itself is a `RBTreeNode*`, so if what I'm thinking is correct, casting it back to `RBTreeNode*` should do what I think it should.

But here

```
  // If nodeInserted's parent's color is BLACK, nodeInserted has replaced a RED NULL node.
  // Red-Black tree properties suggest RED node's parent be BLACK,
  // which is the case currently, so there's nothing to be done.
  else if (nodeInserted->parent->(COLOR??))
    {
      return;
    }
}
```

I don't have access to `nodeInserted->parent`'s `Color` enum. And I don't think casting it to `RBTreeNode` will do much good.

The only solution I know will work is if I rewrite all of my generalized functions to take in `RBTreeNode` as param instead of `Node`, but I really don't want to do that.

Is there a better solution?

Comment: The `typedef` has problems in C — you have `typedef struct Node
{
  Node* left; …`; the type `Node` is either not known or refers to some other type than `struct Node` when the line containing `left` is parsed.  You need `typedef struct Node Node; struct Node { Node *left; … };` to avoid confusion.  C++ has different rules — if your code compiles, you're not using a standard C compiler.

Comment: A better solution would be implementing it in [tag:c++].

Comment: And, casting a pointer of some object type to a pointer of different object type may result in undefined behavior if the resulting pointer is not correctly aligned for the referenced type.

Comment: I'm not sure if you'd be better of with `Node genericNode;` instead of `Node *genericNode;` in your `RBTreeNode`.  There are some rules about common subsequences, etc, but you'd need to look hard at what C provides.  If you want inheritance, use C++ — that's what it's for.

Comment: You check whether `parent` is NULL and then cast to `RBTreeNode`, while `RBTreeNode` has no `parent` field at all... which means that while being represented as `Node*`, you go to the pointer to the RBNode + offset of parent, which means that you are looking at a wrong place. Something is totally wrong here. Maybe your Node field withing the RBTreeNode must not be a pointer, thus it will be kind of an inheritance

Comment: Change `Node* genericNode;` to  `Node genericNode;` in the definition of RBNode. Thus, `->parent` will take you to the offset of the `parent` field in `Node`, regardless of whether it is just Node or RBNode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use a pointer to implement inheritance. Use a `Node` field instead of a pointer:

```
typedef struct RBTreeNode
{
  Node genericNode;
  Color color;

} RBTreeNode;
```

This way, when you cast `Node*` to `RBTreeNode*`, it will have access to all the fields of `RBTreeNode`.

Since you are probably using a c++ compiler, a c++ analogy might help. Having a first field of type `Node` is like having inheritance in c++, i.e. `struct RBTreeNode: Node`. Having a first field of a pointer type is like having virtual inheritance, i.e. `struct RBTreeNode: virtual Node`. Both ways work, until you need a downcast. Virtual inheritance in c++ alerts the reader that you have something fishy about your inheritance hierarchy ("diamond inheritance"), so you should only use it when normal inheritance won't do.